# "options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string." when using PROXY with REACT and Django as backend in LOCALHOST

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-fullstack, django-react

im facing error while im trying to use proxy in **package.json** on react app and connect to django backend api in local host but when i tried to `npm start` i get this error:

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
```

i tried all these steps as shown below and nothing worked pls help.

1- I tried to set `HOST` in **.env** file to http://127.0.0.1:8000 but it didnt work!

2- I've tried:

```
"proxy": "http://django:8000",
```

it changed nothing !!!

then i found a workaround by using the http-proxy-middleware from:
https://sunkanmi.hashnode.dev/how-to-setup-proxy-in-react-with-http-proxy-middleware

but i am not looking for a workaround !!!

My **package.json** look like this

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
```

3- i have also tried:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
"allowedHosts": [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ],
"private":true,
```

didn't work !!!

4- i tried changeing http://127.0.0.1:8000 to http://localhost:8000 didnt work!

5- i tried changeing allowed host in django seetings.py to ['*'] and ['http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'http://localhost:8000'] didnt work !

6- i tried changeing

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS
```

to True and then changing it to

```
CORS_ALLOWed_ORIGINS = [
    
    'http://localhost:3000'
]
```

didnt work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Butterfly

after some searching and changeing some stuff i figured out that when you want to use proxy in the react app if you are connected to a vpn you most disconnect from it to get the react server running :)

```
simplest things can take a lots of time from you in this job
```